# Como efetuar um split da string após contar 50 carateres

Tags: string, vb.net

Tenho que contar 50 caracteres e efetuar um *split* em duas variáveis. O ideal seria efetuar o split no ultimo espaço antes dos 50 caracteres. Isto é para conseguir colocar a morada em duas linhas na base dados.

tenho isto assim:

```
Dim Morada As String = "Avenida luis de camoes, travessa de santa rita numero 588"
Dim CountMorada As Integer = Len(Morada)  'resultado de 57 carateres
```

Queria cortar antes de numero e colocar em duas variáveis.

Comment: Tem algum critério específico, ou é só pegar os 50 primeiros?

Comment: pegar no ultimo espaço, antes dos 50 caracteres, e colocar numa variavel e o restante numa 2 variavel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dá pra fazer um pouco melhor, mas a pergunta não dá detalhes. Precisa pegar até o limite estabelecido onde tiver espaço. Tem função pronta para isto ([`LastIndexOf()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.lastindexof?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_String_LastIndexOf_System_String_System_Int32_)).

```
Imports System
                
Public Module Module1
    Public Sub Main()
        For Each texto in CropText("Avenida luis de camoes, travessa de santa rita numero 588", 50)
            Console.WriteLine(texto)
        Next
        For Each texto in CropText("Avenida luis de camoes, travessa de santa rita", 50)
            Console.WriteLine(texto)
        Next
        For Each texto in CropText("Avenidaluisdecamoes,travessadesantaritanumero588teste", 50)
            Console.WriteLine(texto)
        Next
    End Sub

    Public Function CropText(text As String, limit As Integer) As String()
        If text.Length < limit
            Return New String() {text}
        Else
            Dim position As Integer = text.LastIndexOf(" ", limit)
            If position = -1
                Return New String() {text}
            Else
                return New String() {text.Substring(0, position), text.Substring(position + 1)}
            End If
        End If
    End Function
End Module
```

Veja [funcionando no **.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/c7KflW). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/VB.NET/SplitLimit.vb).

Comment: @SergioTeixeira veja agora.